# VS 12 Site.Master Template not applying to new pages

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm in the process of creating a new website through Visual Studio 2012 that will be updated by co-workers who are not programmers/developers by trade.  This is pretty simple in that all I want to do is have the template I created apply to every new ASPX page I create automatically.  I can copy and paste said template in but I want to make it as painless as possible for people who aren't developers/programmers.  Is there something I'm missing here?